# Bayesian Inference with Continuous prior distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Assume that we have a prior distribution for the probability of success as follows.

```
p = BetaDistribution[6, 14]
```

which we can graph as this

```
Plot[Evaluate[PDF[p, k]], {k, 0, 1}]
```

I would like to use Mathematica to calculate the *posterior* distribution given that we take a sample and we get 420 successes out of a sample size of 1830.

what would be to calculate it and graph it?

Regards.

Comment: A good treatment of the statistical theory behind this can be found on Stats.SE [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/181383/36678).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would like to take some slight shortcuts with regard to Romke's excellent solution while making use of the comfortable features of *Mathematica's* statistical framework.

### Prior

$\theta|I \sim Beta(6,14)$

We can interpret this (conjugate) prior as having seen (or believing in) 18 Bernoulli-trials and having observed 5 successes and 13 failures before making the actual experiment (part of our background information $I$) and code this as:

```
priorDist = With[ { a = 6, b = 14 }, BetaDistribution[a, b] ];
prior = Function[ θ, PDF[ priorDist ] @ θ  ];

Plot[ prior[θ], {θ, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis, Axes-> {True,False} ]
```

[image: prior PDF]

### Likelihood

$y|\theta, I \sim B(n, \theta)$

Given a series of $n = 1830$ Bernoulli-trials with $y = 420$ successes we will have a the Binomal PDF as a likelihood function:

```
likelihood = With[
   {
     n = 1830,
     y = 420
   },
   Function[θ, Likelihood[ BinomialDistribution[n, θ], {y} ] ]
];

Plot[likelihood[θ], {θ, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis, Axes -> {True, False}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Likelihood]

As Romke pointed out, this function is a PDF depending on $\theta$ but not a probability distribution. So it does not integrate to 1:

```
NIntegrate[ likelihood[θ], {θ, 0, 1} ]
```

> 0.00054615

### Posterior

$p(\theta|y,I) \propto p(y|\theta,I) \cdot p(\theta|I)$

[*Bayes-Rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) tells us, that the PDF of the posterior distribution equals the product of the likelihood function and the prior PDF up to a normalizing constant (often called the evidence), which Romke has used in his explicit answer:

$p(y|I) = \int_0^1 p(y|\theta,I) p(\theta|I)$

Being a bit more lazy we can make use of the fact that [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) has an option `Method -> "Normalize"` which will take care to adjusting the PDF to meet the requirements of a probability distribution:

```
posteriorDistribution = ProbabilityDistribution[
    prior[θ] likelihood[θ],
    {θ, 0, 1},
    Method -> "Normalize"
];

Plot[ PDF[ posteriorDistribution ][θ], {θ,0,1},
  Filling->Axis, Axes->{True,False}, PlotRange->All]
```

[image: posterior]

After so many additional data, the posterior (of course) is very close to the likelihood. We can immediately get some summarizing statistics:

```
Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation}@posteriorDistribution] // N
```

> {0.23027, 0.00978554}

[`RandomVariate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) will also work properly, so that we can sample from the posterior:

```
RandomVariate[ posteriorDistribution, 10 ]
```

> {0.222989, 0.227517, 0.218535, 0.228404, 0.226061, 0.235919, 0.234529, 0.230528, 0.22929, 0.247735}

Since the prior and the posterior distributions here have the same functional form ([*conjugate prior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)), we may have immediately used the fact that:

$\theta|y,I \sim Beta(a + y, b + n - y)$

```
Equal[
  PDF[ BetaDistribution[6 + 420, 14 + 1830 - 420], θ ],   
  PDF[posteriorDistribution, θ]
] // Reduce
```

> True

You could also look at `likelihood[θ] prior[θ]//Simplify` to see that the posterior does have the form:

$constant \times \theta^\alpha (1 - \theta)^\beta$

### Update

Note that in general the normalizing constant (e.g. the *evidence*) can be obtained as an expectation:

$p(y|I) = \int p(y,\theta|I)d\theta = \int p(y|\theta,I) p(\theta|I)d\theta = \mathbb{E}[ p(y|\theta,I) ] = \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{L}(\theta)]$

```
posteriorPDF = With[
   { evidence = Expectation[ likelihood[θ], θ \[Distributed] priorDist ] },
   Function[
     θ,
     prior[θ] likelihood[θ] / evidence
   ]
];

posteriorPDF[θ] == PDF[BetaDistribution[6 + 420, 14 + 1830 - 420], θ] // Reduce
```

> True

Comment: I have expanded the solution slightly and made use of `Likelihood` and `Expectation`. Doing so should be more general with regard to discrete or continuous distribution functions.

Answer (score 11):

The posterior distribution for p is a Beta [426, 1424]. You can graph it as you did yourself.

Here is how you can compute in Mathematica.

```
In[1]:= bin = Binomial[n, x]*p^x*(1 - p)^(n - x)

Out[1]= (1 - p)^(n - x) p^x Binomial[n, x]

In[2]:= prior = p^(a - 1)*(1 - p)^(b - 1)/Beta[a, b]

Out[2]= ((1 - p)^(-1 + b) p^(-1 + a))/Beta[a, b]

In[3]:= den = 
 Integrate[bin*prior, {p, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, x >= 0, n >= x}]

Out[3]= (Binomial[n, x] Gamma[b + n - x] Gamma[a + x])/(
Beta[a, b] Gamma[a + b + n])

In[4]:= bin*prior/den // FullSimplify

Out[4]= ((1 - p)^(-1 + b + n - x) p^(-1 + a + x) Gamma[a + b + n])/(
Gamma[b + n - x] Gamma[a + x])
```

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the answer, but I wanted to know how I can pose the problem in Mathematica for it to come back with that answer

Answer (score 11):

I would like to extend asim's solution, which is a function, to a probability distribution.

```
ClearAll[evidence, likelihood, prior, posterior];
likelihood = p^x*(1 - p)^(n - x) (* is always unnormalized ! *)
prior = p^(a - 1)*(1 - p)^(b - 1)/Beta[a, b] (* always normalized *)
evidence = Integrate[likelihood*prior, {p, 0, 1},
Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, x >= 0, n >= x}] (* normalisation of posterior *)
posterior = prior*likelihood/evidence // FullSimplify

(* Out[]= *)
(1 - p)^(n - x) p^x
((1 - p)^(-1 + b) p^(-1 + a))/Beta[a, b]
(Gamma[b + n - x] Gamma[a + x])/(Beta[a, b] Gamma[a + b + n])
((1 - p)^(-1 + b + n - x) p^(-1 + a + x) Gamma[a + b + n])/(Gamma[b + n - x] Gamma[a + x])
```

Nothing new so far. Now for the probability distribution:

```
ClearAll[posteriorDistribution];
posteriorDistribution[a_, b_, x_, n_] = ProbabilityDistribution[posterior, {p, 0, 1}, 
Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, x >= 0, n >= x}];
PDF[posteriorDistribution[6, 14, 420, 1830], 0.21] (* test at p=0.21 *)

4.6369
```

Check this answer by asim's solution in BetaDistribution[] form:

```
PDF[posteriorDistribution[6, 14, 420, 1830], 0.21] == PDF[BetaDistribution[426, 1424], 0.21]

True
```

This probability distribution can be plotted by:

```
Plot[PDF[posteriorDistribution[6, 14, 420, 1830], p], {p, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Several statistical properties work fine:

```
Mean[posteriorDistribution[6, 14, 420, 1830]] // N
StandardDeviation[posteriorDistribution[6, 14, 420, 1830]] // N

0.23027
0.00978554
```

But RandomVariate[] does not:

```
RandomVariate[posteriorDistribution[6, 14, 420, 1830], 5]

RandomVariate[
 ProbabilityDistribution[
 25100175092366680639705706981674366907407305357564535864428789165880\
7774460815201505720742948687064397263210935672027225834571883138571552\
9435073323698076733502611129508985779654636172308803925192878804616791\
4163296382700546574839309987790038929990089862577986787654011552037119\
0043901814728663569787527433974843693348538658624431557074602596292870\
1098499374967102449446582880605618133093761170547891966862458477624898\
28252384878666048 (1 - \[FormalX])^1423 \[FormalX]^425, {\[FormalX], 
0, 1}, Assumptions -> {True, True, True, True}], 5]
```

Anyone here who knows what is going wrong?

Of course, the BetaDistribution[] works fine:

```
RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[426, 1424], 5]

{0.224794, 0.246947, 0.225743, 0.241723, 0.219218}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a snippet that generates the posterior predictive distribution via the above method:

```
BayesRule[priorDist_?DistributionParameterQ, 
  sampleDist_?DistributionParameterQ, params_List, data_List] := 
 Module[
  {bounds, boundReg, likelihood, prior, posterior},
  boundReg = 
   RegionBounds[
    ImplicitRegion[DistributionParameterAssumptions[sampleDist], 
     params], "Sufficient"];
  bounds = Flatten /@ Transpose[{params, boundReg}];
  prior = PDF[priorDist];
  likelihood = 
   Function[Evaluate[params], Likelihood[sampleDist, data]];
  posterior = 
   ProbabilityDistribution[(prior @@ params)*(likelihood @@ params), 
    Sequence @@ bounds, Method -> "Normalize"];
  Return[ParameterMixtureDistribution[sampleDist, 
    If[Length[params] == 1, params[[1]], params] \[Distributed] 
     posterior]]
  ]
```

For example, to solve the problem in the original question:

```
BayesRule[BetaDistribution[6, 14], 
 BinomialDistribution[1830, \[Theta]], {\[Theta]}, {420}]
```

Which creates a distribution that is equivalent to the beta-binomial distribution

Comment: Could you add a demonstration of how it works?